What is causing these mathematical inaccuracies in my code?
After learning that the function representing the velocity of an object with respect to time is the derivative of the function representing the position of the object with respect to time, I made this code in Fortran which would take the function representing the position of an object relative to time, which in this case is X(t) = t^2, as an array, and would output whether the velocity was positive or negative for every second after the object was initially launched.
program veloc
    implicit none
    integer :: t, J
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: X
    X = [ (t**2, t = -1, 100) ]
    do J = 0, 100
        if(X(J) > X(J - 1))then
            print "(a2, i3, a21)", "t=", J, ", Velocity = Positive"
        else if(X(J) < X(J - 1))then
            print "(a2, i3, a21)", "t=", J, ", Velocity = Negative"
        else
            print "(a2, i3, a21)", "t=", J, ", Velocity = Zero"
        end if
    end do
end program veloc

The problem is that it should show the velocity to be positive for every second after the object was initially launched, since X(t) = t^2 is always increasing past t = 0, but instead it shows it to be negative when t = 1 and t = 2.
At first, I had figured the problem was that was t = 0, there wasn't enough information for it to give an accurate result, so I had the array start at -1, and I started the do loop that printed the result at 0, but that didn't fix the problem.

It looks like you believe that there is an element x(-1) in the array x. Do you? (There isn't. You should enable bounds checking and other compiler options which help detect broken code.)

Oh okay. Thanks for telling me.

"so I had the array start at -1," The above code doesn't do this. The lower bound of X is 1, and that array element, X(1), has the value -1 - if you are unsure you can investigate it using the intrinsic function Lbound. To help us help you please edit the question to show the exact code you are currently trying to run.
